# Loading a 1-day pass to a compass card online

Tags: usa, transit, public-transport, california, san-diego

Is there a way to load a 1-day pass to an existing compass card online? When I put in my compass card number [here](https://compasscard.511sd.com/webtix/), I get the following:

[image]

There is no option "[Adult 1-Day Pass](https://www.sdmts.com/fares-passes)". So is it only possible to load this pass in machines (if I want to use the physical card, not the app)?